# how can we set an image dynamically to literal control in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, literals

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind("load", function () {
        $("div#mygalone").slideView()
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind("load", function () {
        $("div#myInstantGallery").slideView({
            easeFunc: "easeInOutBack",
            easeTime: 1200
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can we get the image from server.mapPath(),and set it to the literal control dynamically.
when the user clicks the image,we move to the next image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ashx generic handler to load images dynamically, to load different images you can use query string in which you can pass the name or id or id of next image etc.. Once you have written the handler to load image you can call it simply using `<img src='imageHandlerName.ashx" />`   Here you can find a nice tutorial about [loading images dynamically using ashx handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx).

Answer (score 0):

use the jQuery load function to load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.  create a placeholder for your image and do something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#imageDiv').load("GetImageHTML.aspx?id=picture18");
      });
  });
</script>
```